# Hola, tengo el siguiente problema: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()”

Tags: php, mysql

He bajado wamp con php 7.3.21, con Mysql 5.7.31 y me da el siguiente error Call to undefined function mysql_connect()”?, lo malo es que en versiones mas bajas me funciona y tu indicaste en un post que se puede activar el mysql que esta por default comentado, me puedes indicar como hacerlo, dado que es tendría que modificar mucho y mucha lógica que ya estaba funcionando bien por favor me puedes ayudar
Muy agradecido

Comment: Anexo, esta no es la forma de preguntar, no sabemos ni a quien te estas tratando de dirigir, lee [ask]

Comment: Las funciones _mysql()_ quedaron obsoletas y eliminadas en PHP 5.5, si usas PHP 7, estas ya no funcionarán, debes reemplazarlas con MySQLi